# Pointing Multiple Domains to Different Folders

Tags: zend-framework, mod-rewrite

I tried to my limit. Mod_rewrite had been such a nightmare. My last try is the code bellow and even with www.water.com working I could not make www.wind.com do the same.
In the mod_rewrite log what I get is www.wind.com (HTTP_HOST) being compared to www.water.com all the time. the rewrite never reaches the second group of lines. Someone perhaps know how to achieve that please?

```
RewriteEngine On
----------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?water\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zend/application/Water/ [NC]

# Excludes the redirection for files that physically exist ( -s); symbolic links ( -); and existing directories (-d).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /water.php [NC,L]
----------------------------------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?wind\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zend/application/Wind/ [NC]

# Excludes the redirection for files that physically exist ( -s); symbolic links ( -); and existing directories (-d).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wind.php [NC,L]
----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: is there any reason why you want to do this with mod_rewrite instead of modifying the domains on your host to point to the folder you want on the server?

Comment: not sure, since I'm using zf and trying to keep the zf applications separated on it's own folder structures and do not show any subfolder was what directed me to this. In short the reason is exactly what the title says. I just have no mod_rewrite or server admin skill to figure out the best approach.

Comment: Indeed, seems to me this is better handled at the host level.

Comment: ok, there's smarty ways to do that for sure. I need to try this and I realy don't know yet how it will work, or if it will. Had been trying a lot of thing and any of them made the job until now. I have no access to vhost, its a shared host. This test is being made on local, and I wanna make sure that I can easy deploy it as is (when working). If mod_rewrite is an option it's not a ilegitimate question also. Note, also, that it's a really very commom question over the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the water group, you have two RewriteRules after your sequence of RewriteConds. The first RewriteRule is applied conditionally based upon the result of the RewriteConds.

But won't the second RewriteRule be applied to *all* remaining requests, even requests to the domain `wind.com`? Consider a request for:

`http://wind.com/mycontroller/myaction`

It will fail all the RewriteConds for water, but then get picked up by:

`RewriteRule ^.*$ /water.php [NC,L]`

Won't it?

In any case, it seems like this is better handled at the hosting level. Sounds like you want comepletely distinct ZF apps for each domain, each residing in its own folder, no cross-app sharing (except possibly external libs). In that case, just map the domains - at the hosting level - to their different folders.

Comment: Ok. I will try it with care. I'm just very tired right know to go ahead. But you got exactly the idea. Thank you vey much for the explanation!

Comment: did it locally. Just don't know if I can achieve the same on the remote since I have no access to vhosts. I'll see it after a good sleep.

Comment: Most of the hosts I've seen that allow you to host multiple domains within a single hosting account - even a shared host - will still allow you to specify the folder from which you want each domain to be served. No explicit access to vhost required; they usually handle that internally and offer you a management interface like Cpanel, Plesk, etc. I suspect you'll be able to separate them out that way. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?water\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zend/application/Water/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /water.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?wind\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/zend/application/Wind/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wind.php [NC,L]
```

This should work IMO.